# Equivalent of Array.prototype.map() for iterators like Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The **map** function is very efficient

```
let converted = arr.map(converter);
```

I'm basically looking for a similar alternative with iterator like the Map object, however **map** is not available for **Map** (so much for the fun).

*map.entries().map(...)* or *map.keys().map(...)* don't work either.

You can obviously use a **loop** or create a **helper function**, but that's not the point here. The point is : is there a **built-in function** to map a Map ?

Here is a helper function, but that's off-topic.

```
// this does the job, but does not answer the question
const mapMap = (map, converter) => {
  const result = [];
  map.forEach(entry => result.push(converter(entry)));
  return result;
};
```